# Use CDN version of Video.js

Tags: 7, files, cdn

Until the Video JS Drupal project supports the CDN version, how can we go about overriding the default URL in a custom theme? It looks like there is a plan to [include it in the future](http://drupal.org/node/1460466) but not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in a module, or a theme.

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if (isset($javascript[$path])) {
    $javascript[$path]['data'] = 'absolute URL to the file';
    $javascript[$path]['type'] = external;
  }
}
```

Replace `$path` with the correct value. Normally `$path` is build from the path where the module is installed with `drupal_get_path('module, $module) . '/' $filename`.

Comment: I ended up using http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update which has CDN capability but I marked your answer since it explained what I originally asked for. Thanks!